# Origen de la interjección "¡anda!"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado, interjecciones

Basándome en la pregunta acerca d[el origen de "¡venga!"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19475/12637) como interjección, se me ocurre que un caso similar es el origen de "¡anda!".

> [**anda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2ZGgAPa#CBehDUK)
>
> 1. interj. U. para expresar admiración o sorpresa.
> 2. interj. U. para excitar o animar a hacer algo.
> 3. interj. U. para denotar alegría, como por despique, cuando a alguien le ocurre algo desagradable.

Recordemos como ejemplo aquel famoso anuncio de los Donuts de los años 70, que a uno se le habían olvidado y dice "¡Anda, los donuts!", y luego va con su donut y dice "¡Anda, la cartera!". O imaginemos a [Edadepiédrix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Personajes_de_Ast%C3%A9rix#Edadepi.C3.A9drix) viendo entrar a un centurión en la aldea y exclamando "¡Anda, un romano!".

¿Qué es lo que "anda" en esas expresiones? ¿Cómo llegó a ser "¡anda!" una interjección?

Comment: Pregunta también basada en esta otra: [Usage of 'ándale', 'vamos' and 'anda'](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4621/12637).

Comment: Qué buena cosa. Y ahora que mencionas la relación de _venga_ con _anda_ se me viene a la cabeza **[¡vaya!](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bPkTaY4|bPmU3j2)**, que es universal, y _¡vamos!_, que al menos en Chile lo usamos bastante.

Comment: @Rodrigo aquí también decimos "¡Sí, vamos!" o "¡Vamos, hombre!" para expresar incredulidad. El verbo "ir" da mucho juego. De hecho la propia expresión "¡anda!" se puede intercambiar por "¡ahí va!", que también usa el verbo "ir".

Comment: En Argentina, tiene un significado coloquial muy diferente (obviamente, acentuado en la segunda "a" por el uso del "vos"), que podría definirse como una expresión de descreimiento. Si alguien cuenta algo difícil de creer, el interlocutor puede responderle: ¡Andá! (tal vez una forma abreviada de decir: Andá a contárselo a otro).

Comment: @Gustavson Sí, lo he oído muchas veces eso de "_¡Andá!_", que se corresponde perfectamente con el español "_¡Anda ya!_". Creo que la diferencia es únicamente una cuestión de voseo.

Comment: En inglés se dice *Get out!* con el mismo significado.

Comment: En México, *ándale* puede ser también: *Sí, ya entendiste, ya agarraste la onda, tienes razón, lo expresaste bien, me gusta tu propuesta.*

Answer (score 6):

*¡Anda!* viene de la segunda acepción que has escrito. Al tratarse de una [interjección impropia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjecci%C3%B3n#Interjecciones_impropias) (es decir, que no se trata de una expresión pura, sino que en sí es un sustantivo, verbo, adjetivo...), ha sufrido una evolución desde su significado original. Lo que en un origen era una forma verbal que conmina a alguien para que ande (para que se mueva; para que vaya a algún lugar), con el tiempo ha acabado formando una interjección que expresa sorpresa, alegría...

No es que sea nada especial en sí mismo; todas las interjecciones impropias provenientes de verbos tienen hoy ese significado de sorpresa o reacción (arrea, venga, vaya, dale...). Es la evolución de un imperativo que en el pasado se ha usado con tanta frecuencia que ha creado un propio significado, de reacción y sorpresa ante algo.

Answer (score 5):

Las interjecciones son palabras cuya función es expresar sentimientos (¡ay!), impresiones (¡oh!), reacciones (¡ah!), sonidos que queremos imitar (¡buaaaaa!) o que utilizamos para formular verbalmente comportamientos y relaciones sociales (¡hola!)<sup>1</sup>.

Las interjecciones se pueden clasificar según su *origen* o según su *forma*. Según su origen `anda` sería una interjección impropia (que proceden de otras categorías gramaticales como sustantivos, **verbos**, adjetivos, etc). Según su forma sería una interjección de traslación (palabras o grupos de palabras que en sí no son interjecciones pero que pueden ser utilizadas como tales de forma aislada. *¡Hombre!, ¡Anda!*).

El aspecto más interesante de `¡Anda!` no es que sea una forma verbal en imperativo, si no que es un **verbo de movimiento**. Las interjecciones que provienen de verbos de movimiento pueden expresar el estado cognitivo o emocional del hablante. La experiencia corporal (como el movimiento) sirve como fuente para el vocabulario de estados psicológicos.

Sucede algo muy similar con otras interjecciones provenientes de verbos de movimiento<sup>2</sup>.

- La interjección `¡Anda!` puede expresar admiración, sorpresa, reproche, incredulidad, rechazo, protesta.
- La interjección `¡Vamos!` puede expresar protesta, rechazo, desagrado, acuerdo/desacuerdo, apoyo o enfado.
- La interjección `¡Vaya!` puede expresar sorpresa, protesta, incredulidad, desagrado, acuerdo moderado, intensificador ponderativo, enfado, lamento o compasión.
- La interjección `¡Venga!` puede incredulidad, rechazo, acuerdo/desacuerdo y agradecimiento.

Es decir, que esas interjecciones están representando un cambio (movimiento) en el estado cognitivo del hablante. `El origen de todas estas interjecciones sería, de acuerdo a esta teoría, común: expresarían el "movimiento emocional" del hablante para expresar el grado de certidumbre o duda con respecto a lo hablado o lo ocurrido o una valoración apreciativa de lo mismo.`

---

Referencias:

<sup>1. [Gramática básica para el uso del español: Capítulo 24º Interjecciones](http://users.jyu.fi/~torremor/cursos/gramatica/240.html)</sup>

<sup>2. [Sanne Tanghe, Marcadores derivados de verbos de movimiento: Una aproximación cognitiva](https://books.google.com/books?id=SAxEDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=anda%20expresar%20sorpresa&source=bl&ots=UyC_UUe6I8&sig=n6KMbegXIhTfkfOEyktc0skaCMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjytbnJ6P_VAhVEzIMKHUrYA_cQ6AEIVTAK#v=onepage&q=anda%20expresar%20sorpresa&f=false)</sup>